# error configuring parse application

Tags: amazon-web-services, parse-platform, parse-server

I'm trying to deploy a parse application according to this document https://aws.amazon.com/it/blogs/mobile/how-to-set-up-parse-server-on-aws-using-aws-elastic-beanstalk/ .
I deployed the application in *aws*, created a *mongolab cluster*, copied the connection string in the environment panel and started the application.
If I try to test using curl according the aws tutorial I receive an **interval server error**.
How can I understand what's the problem?

Comment: Did you get this running locally first? It's a good first step towards getting it running on the server, much easier to debug. My bet though, is that you didn't put the user and password for the database URI. it should be something like `https:username:password@<cluster URI>`, not just `<cluster URI>`

Comment: Jake T has the right idea to get it running locally first.  But when you do deploy, it's imperative that you can see the logs, which will be telling you why there is an internal server error.